# WorkManager calls onStopped() for Result.success()

Tags: android, android-workmanager

When I get it right, `onStopped()` should be called, when the `Worker` has been stopped abnormally / is canceled. Not when its work has correctly finished. Is this correct?

> https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker#onstopped
>
> This method is invoked when this Worker has been told to stop. This could happen due to an explicit cancellation signal by the user, or because the system has decided to preempt the task. In these cases, the results of the work will be ignored by WorkManager.

In my case it's the opposite:

When returning from `doWork()` with `Result.success()` then `onStopped()` **is called** and when returning `Result.failure()` it is not.

When calling `WorkManager.getInstance().cancelWorkById(id)` `onStopped()` **is called** as well (this seems correct though).

---

I'm using using `2.0.0-rc01` of `androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx`.

Is there a (reliable) way to get informed when a worker "has finished normally" and when it has been "stopped abnormally"?

I think the latter case would be where `onStopped()` comes into play. Is it a bug maybe?

Comment: I've filed a bug just in case: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128470210

Comment: can you please add some code? this seems like an odd behavior indeed...

Comment: This might be outdated. See the linked bug report. I've managed to arrange myself with the (intended) behavior of the "best-effort policy" when canceling a job.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same. Please take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57592897/why-is-android-worker-finishing-successfully-and-calling-onstopped/58928970#58928970) for more details.
The issue is fixed in **[2.3.0-alpha02](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#2.3.0-alpha02)**. When I updated the version, it works fine.

```
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.3.0-alpha02"
```