# Can't stop worker (ListenableWorker) task when work has finished

Tags: android, worker

I can't seem to find the correct way to stop my worker task. I'm calling `.set(Result.success());` on my `ResolvableFuture<Result>`, but it never triggers `onStopped()` in my class and other subscribed callbacks seem to still be active inside my worker.

- My worker starts and tries to find specific BLE device
- It connects to that device and tries to exit with `Result.success()`
- Tries to exit if worker has run more than 3 minutes.

After calling `Result.success()` after I connected to BLE device it will still hold a active reference to `onConnectionStateChange` inside `connectGatt()` function.

It doesn't even seem to call `onStopped()` even after OS forcibly stops my worker, as I don't ever remember to have seen it in logs.

Even after a new worker is created I still get updates inside the old worker with `onConnectionStateChange`

```
package test;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.concurrent.futures.ResolvableFuture;
import androidx.work.ListenableWorker;
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE;
import static android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M;

public class BluetoothScanWorker extends ListenableWorker  {

    private String TAG = "BluetoothScanWorker";
    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private ResolvableFuture<Result> mFuture;


    public BluetoothScanWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<Result> startWork() {
        mFuture = ResolvableFuture.create();

        Log.d(TAG ,"startWork()");

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= M) {
            ScanSettings settings = (new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER)).build();
            List<ScanFilter> filters_v2 = new ArrayList<>();
            ScanFilter scanFilter = new ScanFilter.Builder()
                    .setDeviceAddress("B8:27:EB:B9:5C:FC")
                    .build();
            filters_v2.add(scanFilter);
            BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                    (BluetoothManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
            bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
            bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().startScan(filters_v2, settings, leScanCallback); // Scan for every BLE device matching my filter

            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    endWork();
                }
            }, 3*60*1000); // End worker after 3 minutes
        }
        return mFuture;
    }


    private void endWork(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= M) {
            Log.d(TAG, "END WORK");
            bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().stopScan(leScanCallback);
            mFuture.set(Result.success());
        }
    }


    @RequiresApi(M)
    private ScanCallback leScanCallback = new ScanCallback() { // Called when I find my BLE device
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            Log.d(TAG ,"onScanResult: " + result.getDevice().toString());
            bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().stopScan(this);
            result.getDevice().connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), true, new BluetoothGattCallback() { // Connect to my BLE device
                @Override
                public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
                    if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                            Log.d(TAG ,"GATT connected successfully");
                            endWork();
                        }
                    } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                        Log.d(TAG ,"GATT disconnected");
                        endWork();
                    }

                }
            },TRANSPORT_LE);

        }
    };


    @Override
    public void onStopped() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Work service stopped");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note, that `ListenableWorker.onStopped()` method is called only if the worker is cancelled or the task is preempted by the system. If the worker has successfully completed, `onStop()` isn't called. The `onStop()` [documentation tells](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker.html#onStopped()):

> This method is invoked when this Worker has been told to stop. ... 
>   This could happen due to an explicit cancellation signal by the user,
>   or because the system has decided to preempt the task. ...

Sometimes `onStop()` callback can be called even if the worker is completed successfully, but it's rather [a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140055777#comment3) that will be fixed in the future. Take a look at this post: [Why is Android Worker finishing successfully and calling onStopped()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57592897/4858777)

Comment: So returning result with SUCCESS or FAIL doesn't tell the worker that it has finished and should stop? So how then I could stop the current running task (without canceling the next one for repeating workers).

Comment: @somerandomusername When you return the SUCCESS or FAIL result from the `startWork()` callback, the worker is considered as finished (stopped), because the work is done, but `onStop()` isn't called as it's designed to be called only in the case of cancellation. If you want the `onStop()` callback to be called when the work is completed, you can just execute it manually from the `startWork()`, before returning the result.

Comment: I was more concerned about worker still being held in memory. For example if I start a timer/delay inside worker and return SUCCESS/FAIL - my timer task will still hold reference and be executed. This wouldn't be the case inside activity after destroying it.

Comment: @somerandomusername Note, that the `ListenableWorker.startWork()` method is executed in the Main thread. If you schedule a Runnable via the thread Handler, the runnable is scheduled in the main thread and of course it won't be cancelled when the worker is finished. Worker even doesn't know that the runnable was scheduled. The right way is to store the reference to the runnable and cancel it from `onStop()` callback that signals about the worker cancellation. I think `onCanceled()` would be a better name of `onStop()` callback, but it was called `onStop()` :)